# Syntaxis equal method in java

Tags: java

What happens if I compare two strings but they are not equal?
So this is my question in code... what does the boolean main will return?
It is necessary to do ? a: b;   ?
Or the main var will get the true or false return?

```
boolean main = args[1].equals("-d")? true: false;
boolean main = args[1].equals("-d");
```

Comment: Both statements should give the same result, as long as you add the close quote missing in the second one.

Comment: It should be obvious that the first example is equivalent to `if(val) return true; else return false;` - so the `if` is redundant.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Some people (like me) are starting to code so it's hard when you are learning new syntax or something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`? true: false` is not necessary, both lines will yield the same result.

Answer (score 1):

from java Documentation for String Class

> public boolean equals(Object anObject)
>
> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if
>   and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that
>   represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

Answer (score 0):

Equals compares two objects by value. Since both args[] and "-d" are Strings, the comparison is valid.

It will return true only if the two stings are the same from character to character, or false if not.

So`? true: false;` is indeed unnecesarry.